# Can I use "with no" with numbers? An example down below

Tags: numerals

Example: - "We have left with no two students"
Is it possible to replace "without" with "with no" in such a sentence? I know these phrases are used interchangeably when there're no significant determiners, but what about numerals?

Answer (score 2):

No, your sentence is not grammatically correct.

In the sentence "We left with no students" the determiner "no" is functioning like the number "zero"; it means "we left with zero students".  It would be impossible to say "We left with zero two students", and for the same reason your sentence is not grammatically correct.

*I suppose it would be possible to say "The [things], with no two being alike, are...", but it's a bit of a stretch.* – Kate Bunting

Comment: Or when the sentence meant to say there were two students there, and they left without them, not taking either of the two along, then the sentence would be 'we have left with neither of the two students'.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, idc about my sentence. I just wanted to know if "with no" could be used with numerals. Can you ever think of a case where it would be possible?

Comment: If a group of things are all different, _no two are alike_. I suppose it would be possible to say "The [things], with no two being alike, are...", but it's a bit of a stretch.